# How to prepopulate slug from foreign key and title?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I need to prepulate slug from title and from title of its foreign key. I've got it partialy working, but instead of title it returns me it's ID.

```
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'description']
    #collection is foreign key
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("collection","title",)}
```

Current result is: `(ID of collection)-(title of item)`

Desired result:  `(title of collection)-(title of item)`

Answer (score 0):

The field is prepopulated from the *value* of other fields, so unless a field actually contains your collection's title, it cannot be used to prepopulate another field out of the box.

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields) states:

> prepopulated_fields doesn’t accept DateTimeField, ForeignKey, nor ManyToManyField fields.

Note also in [prepopulate.js](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/prepopulate.js) the use of `field.val()`: only values of fields present on the page will be used. Since the collection field's values are the IDs, this is what you get. I suppose in your case this could be extended to also support reading option labels for example.